# Using a public method of derived class that is not in interface definition

Tags: c#, oop, ioc-container

New to OOP here. I have defined an interface with one method, and in my derived class I defined another public method. My client code is conditionally instantiating a class of the interface type, and of course the compiler doesn't know about the method in one of the derived classes as it is not part of the underlying interface definition. Here is what I am talking about:

```
public interface IFileLoader
{
    public bool Load();
}

public class FileLoaderA : IFileLoader
{
    public bool Load();
    //implementation

    public void SetStatus(FileLoadStatus status)
    {
        //implementation
    }

}

public class FileLoaderB : IFileLoader
{
    public bool Load();
    //implementation
    //note B does not have a SetStatus method
}

public enum FileLoadStatus
{
    Started,
    Done,
    Error
}
// client code
IFileLoader loader;

if (Config.UseMethodA) 
{
    loader = new FileLoaderA();        
}
else
{
    loader = new FileLoaderB();
}

//does not know about this method
loader.SetStatus (FileStatus.Done);
```

I guess I have two questions:

1. What should I be doing to find out if the object created at run-time has the method I am trying to use? Or is my approach wrong?
2. I know people talk of IOC/DI all the time. Being new OOP, what is the advantage of using an IOC in order to say, "when my app asks
   for an IFileLoader type, use concrete class x", as opposed to simply
   using an App.Config file to get the setting?

Comment: You have to cast loader to the type that has the extra method in order to call the method e,g, ((FileLoaderA)loader).SetStatus(FileStatus.Done);

Comment: If you need to test to see if you can do the cast first use if((loader as FileLoaderA) != null)

Comment: Decided to put the above comments together in an answer.

Comment: Why not just have `FileLoaderA` call `SetStatus` at the end of the `Load` method?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to your two questions and your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35753990/simple-file-loader-with-multiple-implementations-oop-overkill) I'd recommend the following:

#### What should I be doing to find out if the object created at run-time has the method I am trying to use? Or is my approach wrong?

You don't necessarily need to find out the concrete implementation at runtime in your client code. Following this approach you kinda foil the crucial purpose of an interface. Hence it's rather useful to just naïvely *use* the interface and let the concrete logic behind decide what's to do.

So in your case, if one implementation's just able to load a file - fine. If your other implementation is able to the same and a bit more, that's fine, too. But the client code (in your case your console application) shouldn't care about it and just use `Load()`.

Maybe some code says more than thousand words:

```
public class ThirdPartyLoader : IFileLoader
{
    public bool Load(string fileName)
    {
        // simply acts as a wrapper around your 3rd party tool
    }
}

public class SmartLoader : IFileLoader
{
    private readonly ICanSetStatus _statusSetter;

    public SmartLoader(ICanSetStatus statusSetter)
    {
        _statusSetter = statusSetter;
    }

    public bool Load(string fileName)
    {
        _statusSetter.SetStatus(FileStatus.Started);
        // do whatever's necessary to load the file ;)
        _statusSetter.SetStatus(FileStatus.Done);
    }
}
```

Note that the *SmartLoader* does a bit more. But as a matter of separation of concerns its purpose is the loading part. The setting of a status is another class' task:

```
public interface ICanSetStatus
{
    void SetStatus(FileStatus fileStatus);
    // maybe add a second parameter with information about the file, so that an 
    // implementation of this interface knows everything that's needed
}

public class StatusSetter : ICanSetStatus
{
    public void SetStatus(FileStatus fileStatus)
    {
        // do whatever's necessary...
    }
}
```

Finally your client code could look something like the follwing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool useThirdPartyLoader = GetInfoFromConfig();
    IFileLoader loader = FileLoaderFactory.Create(useThirdPartyLoader);

    var files = GetFilesFromSomewhere();
    ProcessFiles(loader, files);
}

public static class FileLoaderFactory
{
    public static IFileLoader Create(bool useThirdPartyLoader)
    {
        if (useThirdPartyLoader)
        {
            return new ThirdPartyLoader();
        }
        
        return new SmartLoader(new StatusSetter());
    }
}
```

Note that this is just *one* possible way to do what you're looking for without having the necessity to determine *IFileLoader*'s concrete implementation at runtime. There maybe other more elegant ways, which furthermore leads me to your next question.

#### I know people talk of IOC/DI all the time. Being new OOP, what is the advantage of using an IOC [...], as opposed to simply using an App.Config file to get the setting?

First of all separating of classes' responsibility is always a good idea especially if you want to painlessly unittest your classes. Interfaces are your friends in these moments as you can easily substitute or "mock" instances by e.g. utilizing [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/). Moreover, small classes are generally more easily maintainable.

The attempt above already relies on some sort of inversion of control. The *main*-method knows barely anything about how to instantiate a *Loader* (although the factory could do the config lookup as well. Then *main* wouldn't know anything, it would just use the instance).

Broadly speaking: Instead of writing the boilerplate factory instantiation code, you could use a DI-Framework like [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/) or maybe [Castle Windsor](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/README.md) which enables you to put the binding logic into configuration files which might best fit your needs.

To make a long story short: You could simply use a boolean *appSetting* in your app.config that tells your code which implementation to use. But you could use a DI-Framework instead and make use of its features to easily instantiate other classes as well. It may be a bit oversized for this case, but it's definitely worth a look!

Comment: khlr: Thank you very much for the thoughtful response. I am now more clear and it's time for me to investigate this idea further. Would you say that it's almost always a good idea to have any class you write implement an interface - at least for unit-test-ability's sake? Is that almost always the case or no? 

I like the idea of keeping classes very small with a single responsibility and passing different objects to other objects to get work done. 

So in your example here, if I were to use a DI framework, would that replace the use/need of the factory? Is a DI framework a factory as it were?

Comment: From a unit-testing perspective I'd say: yes, interfaces are almost always useful. But practically speaking I think they're not always needed and are sometimes even unnecessary "noise" (anyway: if in doubt, I'd use one, because I think it's better to work against an interface instead of a concrete implementation as the latter often leads to tight coupling).
Yes, you're right: if you used a DI framework, the factory-part wouldn't be needed. And yes, [under the hood](https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Aninject%2FNinject+Factory&type=Code) there may be some factories abstracted away for you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
if((loader as FileLoaderA) != null)
{
    ((FileLoaderA)loader).SetStatus(FileStatus.Done);
}
else
{
    // Do something with it as FileLoaderB type
}
```

IoC is normally used in situations where your class depends on another class that needs to be setup first, the IoC container can instantiate/setup an instance of that class for your class to use and inject it into your class usually via the constructor. It then hands you an instance of your class that is setup and ready to go.

EDIT:

I was just trying to keep the code concise and easy to follow. I agree that this is not the most efficient form for this code (it actually performs the cast twice).

For the purpose of determining if a particular cast is valid Microsoft suggests using the following form:

```
var loaderA = loader as FileLoaderA;
if(loaderA != null)
{
    loaderA.SetStatus(FileStatus.Done);
    // Do any remaining FileLoaderA stuff
    return; 
}

var loaderB = loader as FileLoaderB
if(loaderB != null)
{
    // Do FileLoaderB stuff
    return; 
}
```

I do not agree with using is in the if. The is keyword was designed to determine if an object was instantiated from a class that implements a particular interface, rather than if a cast is viable. I have found it does not always return the expected result (especially if a class implements multiple interfaces through direct implementation or inheritance of a base class).

Comment: If you are casting inside of the IF statement you should use `is` instead of `as`.  But for better performance you should use `as` before the if and not do the cast inside the if body.

Comment: Thanks. My first thought was, "interfaces need to be really generic, so it just needs a Load()". But then in my client code, I need to tell the database the status of the load process after calling Load(). SetStatus() *seems* like it belongs in a Loader class on one hand, but then again it doesn't. I guess I am just wondering if it's worth it to have to add all that casting noise, or just put the SetStatus() in the interface and force any user to provide that method. However, the Status method needs app-specific parameters like id, the enum, and optional error message, making it not-generic

Comment: Also, I've read that classes should be small, do *one* thing, and do it well. Is Load() and SetStatus() considered "one" thing or two? Should I create a Logger interface, and provide a StatusLogger class and use that instead? Or should I just make SetStatus() a static method on my static Program class (this is a console application)? But again that doesn't seem to make sense because conceptually, setting the status of loading a file is related to loading the file. Man, once you start trying to go down this road, it can get into a real gray area.